# Error when compiling franekphp standalone app

Tags: php, symfony

When I try to execute the following command :

`docker build -t static-app -f static-build.Dockerfile .`

as described in the documentation :
https://github.com/dunglas/frankenphp-demo

I got this error :

```
> [6/9] RUN composer install --ignore-platform-reqs --no-dev -a ;:                         
0.417 Installing dependencies from lock file                                                
0.418 Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.                    
0.481 Package operations: 0 installs, 0 updates, 5 removals                                 
0.481   - Removing symfony/web-profiler-bundle (v6.4.0)                                     
0.482   - Removing symfony/process (v6.4.0) 
0.482   - Removing symfony/maker-bundle (v1.52.0) 
0.482   - Removing symfony/debug-bundle (v6.4.0) 
0.483   - Removing nikic/php-parser (v4.18.0) 
0.487  0/5 [>---------------------------]   0% 
0.523  5/5 [============================] 100% 
0.534 Generating optimized autoload files 
1.739 65 packages you are using are looking for funding. 
1.739 Use the `composer fund`command to find out more! 
1.741  
1.741 Run composer recipes at any time to see the status of your Symfony recipes. 
1.741  
1.743 Executing script cache:clear [KO] 
1.798  [KO] 
1.798 Script cache:clear returned with error code 255 
1.798 !!  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Symfony\Component\Yaml\ctype_digit() in /go/src/app/dist/app/vendor/symfony/yaml/Inline.php:694
```

I am running a Docker version 24.0.7, build afdd53b
On Ubuntu 23.10.

I try to follow the readme process on the github but can't manage to make it work.
The project works well as a worker but though.

Comment: If you search for your error message, there are many similar questions, the answer to most of them seems to be to install the php ctype extension.  Did you see those questions, or try doing that?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Anyway, his question is more about why did an eror occurs while building an image which should've work. His question is related to building and running frankenphp-demo, it' in a Docker context. You can't just say 'install php ctype extension', plus this is not sufficiant as shown in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I have managed to reproduced and fixed the problem.

[image]

It look like the dockerfile of FrankenPhp has been updated last week and maybe introduce an error.

https://github.com/dunglas/frankenphp-demo/commit/90ea1971d6b008ea4d1c7083058e8e8b4415c52a

See, it look like the PHP Extension ctype is enabled after executing `composer install`.

I'm gonna edit the `static-build.Dockerfile` file to remove the `--ignore-platform-reqs`:
https://github.com/dunglas/frankenphp-demo/blob/90ea1971d6b008ea4d1c7083058e8e8b4415c52a/static-build.Dockerfile

```
# static-build.Dockerfile
    composer install --no-dev -a ; \
...
```

Now we can see that the ctype extension is missing in the error details:

[image]

It look like this Dockerfile don't work and the ctype/iconv extension should be enabled manually before trying to run `composer install`

To do so, update the Dockerfile such as:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 dunglas/frankenphp:static-builder

# Prepare the app
WORKDIR /go/src/app/dist/app
COPY . .

# +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
RUN apk update \
    && apk add php83-ctype \
    php83-iconv \
    php83-openssl \
    php83-session
# +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

RUN echo APP_ENV=prod > .env.local ; \
    echo APP_DEBUG=0 >> .env.local ; \
    composer install --ignore-platform-reqs --no-dev -a ; \
    composer dump-env prod

# Build the static binary
...
```

Note: I've added the `php83-session` either since it's required to run the Framework, otherwise you'll encouter this error: `In FrameworkExtension.php line 437. Session support cannot be enabled as the session extension is not installed . See https://php.net/session.installation for instructions.`

THen I was finally able to build the image:

[image]

Comment: [Please do not post images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6089612)

Comment: I Have post image where it's relevant @Don'tPanic, this is to prove that I've reproduced and fix the issue. It show that I've tried and solve this. In my opinion the image are relevant AND I've written the errors

Comment: The text is relevant.  It should be text, not an image.  Please read the link I posted.

Comment: I could've post text indeed. I've removed those image and container so I can't post text anymore. Sorry